# unknown error with gputools R version 3.1.2 Cuda 6.5, GeFource GTX 750 TI

Tags: r, gpu

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet" Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

when I tried to follow this example http://dsnotes.com/blog/2015/06/04/installing-cuda-toolkit-and-gputools/

I received the following :

```
library(gputools)
> N <- 1e3
> m <- matrix(sample(100,size = N*N, replace = T), nrow = N)
> system.time(dist(m))
   user  system elapsed 
  5.268   0.000   5.251 
> system.time(gpuDist(m))
Error in gpuDist(m) : unknown error
In addition: Warning message:
In gpuDist(m) : distance function : malloc and memcpy
Timing stopped at: 0.208 0.02 0.393
```

Comment: The R version is not important here (although version 3.1.2 is outdated). The CUDA version you are using and the model of your graphics card would be more important information in this case. I think your GPU just doesn't have enough memory for this problem. Try to reduce N and start again (you may also need to reboot your computer unless you want to type a little CUDA code to reset/delete the memory in your graphics card, which could be cluttered after such an error).

Comment: In any case I can't reproduce/confirm the error. Your code works fine on my computer (CUDA v7.0, GeForce GTX 760, 4GB).

Comment: I have a GeForce GTX 750 TI, and using cuda 6.5 ... I will try it again once I get home from work, to see if a restart was the only issue.

Comment: From what I have found it seems that this model has 2 GB, which may not be sufficient for the memory-intensive dist calculation. I have noticed that gputools is not good at error-handling when it comes to memory issues.

Comment: Is there another package you would recommend for my setup? Or, do I have to figure out how to make a wrapper function on my own in order to use my gpu like in this post? http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/accelerate-r-applications-cuda/

Comment: I have no experience with other R packages using GPUs and I don't think there are many. Personally, I'd probably write a CUDA program myself to be called from R. However, it might be worth taking a look at [this package](https://github.com/Rth-org/Rth). I haven't tested it, but I think it looks interesting.

Comment: I tried it again, and I still get the error.

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer** - this contains some self promotion.

I am not very familiar with `gputools`, I did try it initially when I first started GPU computing with R but I found it to be annoyingly difficult to install and I also didn't like being stuck with a NVIDIA card (although they are excellent cards).  If you aren't stuck on the CUDA train I would like you to consider my `gpuR` package which you can find on my [github](https://github.com/cdeterman/gpuR).  The core of the package utilizes the [ViennaCL](http://viennacl.sourceforge.net/) library to make GPU computing extremely simple.  This also utilizes an OpenCL backend making it portable to essentially any GPU card.

I just recently added `dist` methods to calculate a the row-wise Euclidean Distance matrix.  So if you just need Euclidean distance, this would be an alternative to `gpuTools`.  All the functions in the package are intended to be identical to `base` R functions (except applied to my S4 classes).

```
library(gpuR)

# R matrix
mat <- matrix(rnorm(1e+06), 1000, 1000)

# vclMatrix (from gpuR)
vcl_A <- vclMatrix(mat)

# quick 'benchmark'

# base R
system.time(dist(mat))
user  system elapsed 
4.726   0.000   4.679 

# vclMatrix from gpuR
system.time(dist(vcl_A))
user  system elapsed 
0.092   0.000   0.053 

# check equivalence
res <- as.matrix(dist(mat))
gpu_res <- dist(vcl_A)

all.equal(res, gpu_res[], check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

Seeing that you have CUDA installed already on a Linux system it should be simple for you to install this package.  I have installation instructions on my [github wiki](https://github.com/cdeterman/gpuR/wiki/Build-Instructions-for-Linux).

I am about to submit this package to CRAN but I would love to have additional users exploring the package so I can continue to improve it.

**EDIT**

Regarding your original error, you can see in the [distance.cu file](https://github.com/nullsatz/gputools/blob/master/src/distance.cu) on line on 834 that the error stems from a failure to allocate the CUDA memory.  That said, your matrix size should be easily handled by that card.  Also, the CUDA version shouldn't matter that much as the package release itself states that it only requires >= 5.0.  As stated in the comments, you can try restarting your computer or reinstalling/upgrading CUDA but I cannot provide a clean answer to the bug itself.  If you have your heart set on using gputools you should submit a bug report on the [github page](https://github.com/nullsatz/gputools).

Comment: I really don't see how this answers the question. At all.

Comment: @talonmies The OP asked originally how to run `gpuDist` from `gputools`.  In the comments, he asks about an alternative package.  This answer provides a solution to that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,  I will check it out. Now, are you suggesting that I should update my cuda version to better allocate memory, or get a better ( or second) graphics card? Lastly, my heart is not set on using gputools, but it had some of the features I wanted already packed into one package like hclust, lm, and cor. I am trying to get into chemometrics, and would love to utilize my 8 cores and my gpu for processing spectra.

Comment: @Steveburnett I would try a simple CUDA program to test you installation.  It is possible there is an installation error somewhere.  If that works then check the most recent version of CUDA supported by your card.  Mainly check if a self-contained CUDA program works first and update your question.